# How to manualy upload file to server from node app

Tags: node.js, express, restify

I have server which handles file upload.
It processes file in memory.
After processing is finished I have to upload the file to the next server.
How I can do this?

I am using `express` to handle file upload to first server and `restify` client to communicate with second server.

So I have something like this:

```
app.post('/first-server',function(req,res,next){
    var file_path = req.files.somefile.path;

    var param1 = req.param('param1') + 'modified';
    var param2 = req.param('param2') + 'modified';

    doSomethingWithFile(file_path,function(modified_file_stream){
        // now I want to post file (stream) and modified params (param1 & param2) to second server
    });

});
```

Comment: What about streaming file content to another server?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
app.post('YourRoute', function (req, res) {
    var request = require('request');
    req.pipe(request.post('/YourAnotherServerURL/Route:3300')).pipe(res);
});
```

Your `HTTPRequest` is a stream. So, you could actually pipe the current stream into the your next server; inside your express route.

For more information check [this](http://loose-bits.com/2012/08/02/nodejs-read-write-streams-pipes.html)

Comment: But along with file some other params (payload) are POSTED to the first server. And I have to change them a little bit (filter) and also modify uploaded file - I resize uploaded image using `gm`. So I dont want to pipe - I want to create completly new request to second server...